# return value from phonegap confirm callback function to calling function

Tags: javascript, cordova

how to get return value from phonegap confirm callback function to calling function.I want to return sureDelete set by callback function.

```
var DeleteGroup= function(){

    var sureDelete;
    var render = function() {        
        promptfun();
        return sureDelete;
     };

     var promptfun = function(){
         navigator.notification.confirm(
             'Are you sure you want to delete group?',
              confirmHandler,
             'Delete Group',      
             ['Cancel','Delete']  
         );
     };

     var confirmHandler = function(buttonIndex){
         if(buttonIndex == 2){
             sureDelete = true;
         }else{
             sureDelete = false;
         }
     };

     return {
         render:render
     };
};
```

Comment: Your callback should trigger the desired behavior. If it is a async operation this is the correct way.

Comment: I am using above code in marionette controller using requirejs i am loading above file and in controller i have acceess it like this

var obj = new DeleteGroup();
obj.render();

but it is stuck in confirmHandler and not returning value from render function. is there any alternate way?

Comment: You should explain your objective and the desired behavior.

Comment: My guess is that `navigator.notification.confirm` is asynchronous causing your render method to return `undefined`. Does your code goes as `...; var result = obj.render(); /* here you expect result to be true or false but you gets undefined */`? I so you must to change to `...; obj.render(function(result){ /* here you use result (true/false) */});` and change your `DeleteGroup#render` implementation to properly account for the callback and pass it around when needed.

Comment: Maybe you need to do something like this http://jsfiddle.net/qLrhuhgv/